# appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget has no effect

Tags: android, widget

I simply want to update my widget when it is resized in Jelly Bean.

So I use this code:

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
@Override
public void onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(Context context,
        AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int appWidgetId,
        Bundle newOptions) {
    Log.d("DEBUG_TAG", "I want to update Widget: "+appWidgetId);
    appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId,
            getRemoteViews(context, minWidth, minHeight));
    Log.d("DEBUG_TAG", "Widget "+appWidgetId+"should have been updated");
    super.onAppWidgetOptionsChanged(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetId,
            newOptions);
}
```

Unfortunately nothing happen.

My logcat clealy says that the widget should be updated, as expected, but the onUpdate is never called!

```
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {

    final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
    Log.i("", "***Update "+N+" Widget*** ");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
        Log.i("", "***Widget*** "+appWidgetId );
```

But nothing happen.

I have checked that when I create my Widget the ID is correct (id is 29 in my case)
29 is shown in the log when onAppWidgetOptionsChanged is called
29 is shown in the log when widget created

Thank a lot for any help.

Comment: "Unfortunately nothing happen" -- what does `getRemoteViews()` do? "My logcat clealy says that the widget should be updated, as expected, but the onUpdate is never called!" -- `onUpdate()` is not called in response to a resize event or a call to `updateAppWidget()`. Here is a sample project showing updating an app widget's contents based upon a resize event: https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/AppWidget/Resize

Comment: You are just telling me that onUpdate() is not called at updateAppWidget()... Does not sound so obvious for me....

Comment: "You are just telling me that onUpdate() is not called at updateAppWidget()" -- why would it be? `onUpdate()` *calls* `updateAppWidget()`. Do you like infinite recursion?

Comment: Calling onUpdate(context, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context), ids) in updateAppWidget fixed my issue and does not cause infinite loop....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding Commonsware answer, I might be doing something wrong, but I need to call onUpdate manually in the onAppWidgetOptionsChanged method.

updateAppWidget has absolutely no effect (I double checked the widget id and the remoteview)

I would be pleased to hear better solution, but that's the only way I can make the widget refresh!

```
    int[] ids = {appWidgetId};
    onUpdate(context, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context), ids);
```

Comment: I'm using the same call onUpdate() to make it work. Still having issues with updateAppWidget() call having no effect on app start/update, whether called from main thread or not, the launcher doesn't seem to consider it at all. Bugged launcher IMO.